# cannot retrive image from sql server to vb .net form

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

I am trying to display user with image using id; it throws an exception

> Conversion from type 'Byte()' to type 'Byte' is not valid.

When I remove image code; its working fine displaying other data.

```
If rdbtninvestigator.Checked = True Then
            Dim mycmd1 As New SqlCommand("Select * From investigator where id=@id ", connection)
            mycmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtid1.Text

            Dim table As New DataTable
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(mycmd1)
            adapter.Fill(table)
            If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then


                lblid.Text = table.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
                lblname.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
                lblusername.Text = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()
                txtpassword.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString()
                Dim img As Byte
                img = table.Rows(0)(4)
                Dim ms As New MemoryStream(img)
                picuser.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

                btnupdate.Enabled = True
                btndelete.Enabled = True


            Else
                MsgBox("Account does not exist")
                btnupdate.Enabled = False
                btndelete.Enabled = False



            End If
```

Comment: `Dim img As Byte` The way you've written it, this object represents a _single byte_, not an array. I suspect you want something like `Dim img As Byte()` (sorry if that's not the right VB syntax. But basically you need to declare it as an array not a single item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images stored in databases are stored as a byte array.  The error message you're getting say you are attempting to store the image in a byte variable, not a byte array.

The line of code you need to add/correct is:

```
Dim image As Byte()
```

That line creates a variable of type `Byte()`, a byte array.